# Should variables be commented in VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Since I have started programming in VBA I have used 
[this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic/Coding_Standards#Commenting_Code) website as basically my bible.  However I don't see any mention of whether or not to comment my variables.

After doing a fair bit of research online I have been able to find very little regarding the topic at all.  So I though I would see about getting your guys opinion on whether or not commenting variables is worth it.  Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is not the right fit for Stack Overflow because it is primarily opinion based.

Comment: Should you comment your variables? No. You should name them properly. If a variable has a nice descriptive name, there's nothing left to comment on.

Comment: On another note, this question ***is not*** Primarily Opinion based. It's objectively answerable, but this is not the right SE site to answer it on.

Comment: @RubberDuck -- You might be right, although the question specifically says "I would see about getting your guys **opinion** on whether or not commenting variables is worth it."  I know that's just wording and not substantive, though.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to comment my variables when I think their purpose might be confusing. Generally, I try to create descriptive variable names so that I can tell at first glance to what they refer. However, with some calculations, and in some circumstances, it's difficult to determine just from the variable name its intended function. In these cases, I'd throw in a comment.

I'd say overall, it should be left to the user's discretion. Do you think it's difficult to understand what it does? If so, comment it.

Comment: Down voted for answering an off-topic question.  Answering questions like this encourages this behavior.  This question does not belong on stack overflow.

Comment: @roryap I didn't realize this type of question did not meet StackOverflow standards. I'll be more mindful in the future